# Programming a friends list feature

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'd like to firstly point that I'm not very good at advanced MySQL just yet. So please forgive me. What I am trying to do is create a friends list like what's in the image below:

[image]

Here is my db structure:

friends table:
[image]

users table:
[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php  $query3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE node1id = '{$myuserid}'");
        foreach($query3->result() as $row1) {
        echo $row1->node1id."<br>"; } ?>
```

I know this code isn't logically correct. What I am trying to do is pull in the users table. And if relationType = friends, display firstname and lastname of the user in the friends list. I have two variables. $selectedId and $myuserid. $selectedId is the id of the profile the user is viewing. and $myuserid is the id of the logged in user. How would I code this type of feature logically?

Comment: So do you want to display all mutual friends that `user1`(logged in user) may have with `user2` (profile being viewed) ?

Comment: Yeah I need to do mutual friends too. Lol this stuff is confusing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username FROM users 
WHERE userid IN 
    (SELECT node2id FROM friends WHERE node1id = '{$myuserid}' 
    AND relationType = 'friends')
```

and

```
echo $row1->username
```

For mutual friends you could do this

**EDIT**: Just realised last version of this wasn't right, fixed now (untested)

```
SELECT username FROM users 
WHERE userid IN 
    (SELECT node2id FROM (
        (SELECT node2id FROM friends WHERE relationType = 'friends' AND node1id <> '{$myuserid}' AND node1id IN
            (SELECT node2id FROM friends WHERE relationType = 'friends' AND node1id = '{$myuserid}'))) 
         WHERE node2id IN (SELECT node2id FROM friends WHERE relationType = 'friends' AND node1id = '{$myuserid}'))
```

This first selects friends, then it selects the friends of those friends which is not equal (not equal is <>) to yourself. It then only selects from that list the friendIDs which match your your own friend IDs. It then selects the name of these users from the users table.

Comment: I'm getting error's with that code. and what exactly does the IN feature do?

Comment: What kind of errors? Try removing the 'as fromFriends' bit, does that help? The bit in the brackets returns a list of userids of friends like (34243423,6546546456,453534535,6556744) and the IN bit means the first SELECT will only select usernames from the users table that have a userid that is IN (i.e. exists in) that list

Comment: Okay cool it works. Thanks man! And how would I do a mutual friend query? Do you think you can help me with that real quick?

Comment: Well. Actually I'll figure that out at another time. One thing I am noticing is it is only displaying the friendship to the my account and nobody else's

Comment: Ok well I added how I would do mutual friends, anyway good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select inside of a select like below:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE idusers IN (
   SELECT node2id FROM friends WHERE node1id = $myUserId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get all friends of a particular user (`$selectedid`), and determine whether or not each of their friend is a mutual friend:

```
SELECT    b.*, 
          c.myfrnd IS NOT NULL AS isMutual
FROM      (
          SELECT IF(node2id = '$selectedid', node1id, node2id) AS usrfrnd
          FROM   friends
          WHERE  '$selectedid' IN (node1id,node2id) AND
                 relationType = 'friends'
          ) a
JOIN      users b ON a.usrfrnd = b.userid
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT IF(node2id = '$myuserid', node1id, node2id) AS myfrnd
          FROM   friends
          WHERE  '$myuserid' IN (node1id,node2id) AND
                 relationType = 'friends'
          ) c ON b.userid = c.myfrnd
ORDER BY  isMutual DESC
```

The column `isMutual` will contain `1` if the friend is a mutual friend, otherwise `0` if not. Mutual friends show up first in the result set.

The thing you have to consider is that a user could be in either columns `node1id` or `node2id`, so in order to get a consistent join, we use a subselect to force the friends of the parameter userids (`$selectedid` and `$myuserid`) to be in the same column.

Let me know how this works.